# In Swift how do you simply "make a variable" a RegexComponent?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I have code like this ...

```
func blah() {
  if let r = someString.firstMatch(of: /([abc])(\d{2})$/) {
    blah blah .. String(r.1), String(r.2)
  }
}
```

Normally with a regex, i'd just keep the regex-guts as a variable.

Hence, something like this:

```
let RX: RegexComponent = /([abc])(\d{2})$/

func blah() {
  if let r = someString.firstMatch(of: RX) { ..
}
```

I have completely and absolutely failed to be able to do this, and have searched for hours.

some suggest you need `any RegexComponent`

```
let RX: any RegexComponent = /([abc])(\d{2})$/

func blah() {
  if let r = someString.firstMatch(of: RX) { ..
}
```

But it simply doesn't work.

the argument of `firstMatch#of` is undoubtedly a `RegexComponent`.

How the heck can I make/set a variable that is a `RegexComponent` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let RX = /([abc])(\d{2})$/
```

Now, since it works, you can Alt+click on the var name (`RX`), and the type inference (ie, type of the variable "deduced" by the compiler) should tell you it's a `Regex<Substring>`

So you can write also:

```swift
let RX: Regex<(Substring, Substring, Substring)> = /([abc])(\d{2})$/
```

I don't have the full explanation, since I haven't played with the new `Regex`, but I guess it's because `RegexComponent` is `protocol`, so there is no really an `init`, and there must be something with "literals": `BareSlashRegexLiterals`

Example:

```swift
let string = "b12"
let RX: Regex<(Substring, Substring, Substring)> = /([abc])(\d{2})$/
if let match = string.firstMatch(of: RX) {
    print(match.output)
    // ("b12", "b", "12")
    // (original, capture#1, capture#2)
}
```

Comment: Xcode 14.2 tells me it's a `Regex<(Substring, Substring, Substring)>`.

Comment: Interesting @robmayoff I used 14.3 I think.